# Can a asset manifest file be of coffee or sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

When I deploy into production, I found out that a few of the manifest files are not precompiled. And I realize that these manifest files all have extensions like .sass or .js.coffee

I did include these in the `application.rb` like `config.assets.precompile << 'admin.js.coffee'`.

So is it the case that manifest files can't be things other than plain css/js?

UPDATE

I have a fish.sass, and doing `config.assets.precompile << 'fish.sass'` won't do a thing. However if I do `config.assets.precompile << 'fish.css'` it will compile properly. Seems weird that I have to specify a non-existent file to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `fish.css` does "exists". Before compiling the assets, rails will look your filenames, and parse the files according to their extension. so sass files will be rendered in css, coffee in js, etc.

Comment: that makes sense, I guess I missed that when I read the guide.

Answer (score 1):

The manifest files can include other files such as sass, coffee. When you deploy your app, you need to run `rake assets:precompile`. This will precompile all your asset files.

If you have other files, you need to add this inside your production.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( admin.js, admin.css )
```

Make sure you have this as well in your production.rb

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

**You must name the manifest files with extension `.js` and `.css`, then add the same names inside `production.rb`.**

Comment: thanks but you are not answering the question at all. I did all those (not live compile though) and I just happen to use .js.coffee and .css.sass

Comment: yes I ran it, most stuff compiles, apart from the one I mentioned

Comment: you must name the manifest files with extension `.js` and `.css`, then add the same names inside production.rb.